# DotNetZip unzip throw Ionic.Zip.BadStateException

Tags: c#, zip, aes, dotnetzip

I have zipped a folder of 1.5 GB in multiple zip files of 100 MB using aes256 encryption. When I tried to unzip, after 70 - 75% of files were unzipped the error

```
Ionic.Zip.BadStateException
```

was thrown with the message "The final hash has not been computed.". Please tell me why it is happening and how can I fix this.
I found the same issue [here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/16105), but without a solution.
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround, using `zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;` seems to fix the bug. With this, zipping is slower, but it's the only way.